# Magento set default associated product to display

Tags: magento

I have a configurable product which have 2 associate products. I want to able to select, which one display by default in product page. How to do this?

Comment: You should probably add more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using below extension:

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher